# What is an ideal camera to use with the Java Media Framework?

Tags: java, camera, jmf

Is there is a camera that is ideally suited to use with the Java Media Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web-cams should work just fine, but note that many will (also) offer higher resolutions and frame rates than JMF can support.

For that reason I would say 'a cheap one'.